# Grep multiple git lines since previous release

Tags: git, release

I use git command to manage my SVM daily activities. For python, I utilize library 'poetry', and a Makefile to publish a library (look at: https://github.com/trouchet/eule). Since each release tags a commit message "release/ tag v$$(poetry version -s)", I find a good idea to list all commits sofar since last release to evaluate the release batch.

After some while researching and pondering, I came to command below.

`git log --pretty=format:"%h - %s (%ad)" --date=short --grep="release/ tag v$(poetry version -s)"..HEAD`

The last option `..HEAD` SHOULD list the all commits since grepped only line. It does not happen. I ask for help in case you know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following command pipeline works for me:

```bash
git log --oneline "$$(git rev-list -n 1 "v$$(poetry version -s)")..$$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```

Sorry for disturbing.